# Testing Rails model uniqueness with duplicate entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I have a restriction on my Rails DB to force unique usernames, and I create a user at the start of each of my model tests.  I'm trying to create a second user with the same username as the first and I expect this to not be valid, but it is returning as valid.

I've tried tweaking the code to use the new, save, and create methods when generating new users but with no success.

Registration Model:

```
class Registration < ApplicationRecord
  @username_length = (3..20)
  @password_requirements = /\A
    (?=.{8,}) # Password must be at least 8 characters
    (?=.*\d) # Password must contain at least one number
    (?=.*[a-z]) # Password must contain at least one lowercase letter
    (?=.*[A-Z]) # Password must contain at least one capital letter
    # Password must have special character
    (?=.*[['!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&']])
  /x

  validates :username, length: @username_length, uniqueness: true
  validates :password, format: @password_requirements
  validates :email, uniqueness: true
  has_secure_password
  has_secure_token :auth_token

  def invalidate_token
    self.update_columns(auth_token: nil)
  end

  def self.validate_login(username, password)
    user = Registration.find_by(username: username)
    if user && user.authenticate(password)
      user
    end
  end
end
```

Registration Tests:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Registration, type: :model do
  before do
    @user = Registration.new(
      username: '1234',
      password: 'abcdeF7#',
      email: 'test@test.com',
      name: 'One'
    )
  end
  it 'should not be valid if the username is already taken' do
    @user.save!(username: '1234')
    expect(@user).not_to be_valid
  end
end
```

I would expect this test to pass due to it being a duplicate username.

Comment: In the sample you provided there no another user created before each test?

Comment: `save!` will raise an error if user not valid, so `expect` will never be executed when user is not valid.

Comment: ^^ What Fabio said ,... I think you can just remove the `@user.save!` line entirelly

Comment: Thanks all, will definitely give that a try!  Fabio-- I am not creating any other users before each test, I thought creating only one would be sufficient.  Would another user need to be created for this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As fabio said, you dont have second Registration object to check uniquness. 
You just checked your saved @user is valid or not which is always valid and saved in DB. To check your uniqueness validation you can do something like this -

```
RSpec.describe Registration, type: :model do
  before do
    @user = Registration.create(
      username: '1234',
      password: 'abcdeF7#',
      email: 'test@test.com',
      name: 'One'
    )
    @invalid_user = @user.dup
    @invalid_user.email = "test1@test.com"
  end
  it 'should not be valid if the username is already taken' do
    expect(@invalid_user.valid?).should be_falsey
  end
end
```

Comment: Checking whether it’s falsey makes sense in this context.  I tried using the syntax you provided and the test is still returning true when it should be false.  The two users have the same username output when the test is run, and I’m wondering if it’s still true because the users aren’t actually being saved to the db.  If that’s the case would it make more sense to use a conditional to force the proper result?

Answer (score 1):

`@user.save!` will raise an error even before reaching the expect as mentioned in comments by Fabio

Also, if it is important to you to test db level constraint you can do:

```
expect { @user.save validate: false }.to raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique)
```